# Is it correct to use Laravel translation files to store static data with business rules?

Tags: laravel, architecture, translation

### Good afternoon, everyone

I have a question about how to achieve the following.

I have data that will be static, meaning it will never change. So, I've decided to place this data in arrays (as if they were configs).

When using internationalization, my idea was to use translation files (es, en, etc.). However, this data contains business rules, let me explain:

The application involves generating settlements for tabletop role-playing games. There are different types of settlements: Trading Posts, Villages, Towns, Cities, and so on. Each of these settlements has associated attributes, for example, Trading Posts have Origin, Specialty, Age, State, etc.

Trading Posts do have a model with a table (id, user_id, name, description, origin, specialty, etc.). But when generating them, these static tables/arrays are consulted. Here's an example of the 'origin' array:

```php
    'origin' => [
        'dice_type' => '1d8',
        'result' => [
            1 => [
                'description' => 'Accidental. The trading post came about due to an accident, such as a caravan breaking down or mistaken directions. What was set up to deal with the accident eventually became the trading post.',
                'special' => null,
                'sub_table' => null,
                'table_modifications' => null,
            ],
            // ... (other entries)
        ],
    ],
```

When the user is creating a Trading Post and presses the generate button, they'll get a result from 1 to 8. This result is stored in the 'origin' column of the 'trading_posts' table. So, when retrieving this Trading Post, it knows to go to this same array and fetch the data under the corresponding key.

The dilemma is whether it's correct to store this in translation files since these are business rules. However, having an array in each language makes internationalizing the application much simpler.

I should note that I don't want to use JSON fields in the table or the spatie-translatable package.

Is the approach I'm taking correct, or should I do it differently? What do you think?

Thanks in advance.

For now, I've only created several associative arrays in the translation files. I'd like to have a clear approach on how to tackle a solution that isn't tightly coupled to the framework.

#### edit

To explain myself better. Let's take into consideration the following class:

```php
    class TradingPostData
        {
            protected string $diceType;
            protected array $results;
            protected ?array $subTables;
        
            protected function __construct(array $data)
            {
                $this->diceType = $data['dice_type'];
                $this->results = $data['results'];
                $this->subTables = $data['sub_tables'];
            }
        
            public static function fromArray(array $array): TradingPostData
            {
                return new self($array);
            }
        
            // ...
        }
```

```php
    $originTradingPostData = TradingPostData::fromArray(__('settlements.trading_post.origin))
```

Is it correct that the array that I am passing to this data model is the array of the translation file?

Comment: Considering these files are specifically built for localization, I would suggest the answer to be no, its not good practice as you're not using them for their intended purpose https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization
That being said, it would make sense for you to build your own mapping feature to determine what string is passed to the view. This could be a relational based table structure with your result string 'keys', or hard coded string 'keys' in some 'TrandingPostService' class you can make. Then on top of that, use the localization files to modify the language of those string 'keys'